Is this considered damaged passport? Peeled off a sticker in the passport cover
I was preparing our passport for our upcoming travel and saw that a sticker from my recent travel was stuck in the backcover of my passport. When I removed it, the cover was peeled off.
Will this be an issue? Everything is intact and I'm afraid because I am flying to Japan in a month.


This question is similar to: Passport - small damage on passport. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

What do you have in the back of the page? In general: do it seems tempered? So it is mostly on page with personal information (and photo) and visa; and binding (which include detached cover), which may hints replaced pages. So I would say no problems

@giacomocatenazzi the scuffed area were just general information. It's the back cover and mamy passport number is also below and intact. Aside from that all is intact and good condition. It's just it was scuffed after i removed a sticker

Out of interest, what was the sticker? Why didn’t you just leave it there?
